# How to access partitions inside a logical volume from the host machine?

Tags: centos, virtualization, lvm, partition

On a Virtual Machine Host Server I have a logical volume, `/dev/my_volume_group/some_disk`. The Logical volume "some_disk" has two partitions on it that were created by the guest machine. A swap and an ext3.

How can I access the ext3 partition from the host machine? I can only see the logical volume, not the partition(s) inside it? The host is a CentOS 6 Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important: Either mount the filesystems inside the partitions read-only or make sure they are not mounted by a VM.

Than you can use the `kpartx` tool to mount the partitions, and if this is not available, use the `offset` option for `mount`. More details can be found in @kupson's and my answer to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/363754/how-can-i-split-a-drive-image-created-with-dd-into-separate-files-for-each-par/363761#363761), just use the path to your logical volume instead of the image file name.

Comment: Thanks! For completeness, its `kpartx -a /dev/my_volume_group/some_disk` and then you'll be able to use `/dev/mapper/my_volume_group-some_disk1` and `/dev/mapper/my_volume_group-some_disk2`